# Richfaces 4 queue, javascript code not generated

Tags: java, queue, richfaces

I have a page where search is triggered on each keystroke. Page has *ajax:queue* tag with *ignoreDupResponses* attributed set to **true** to avoid unnecessary renderings on client side. However, behavior was the same as without ajax:queue added. Compared with code from richfaces showcase, even deployed showcase on local machine (to have exactly the same richfaces version - 4.3.8-snapshot), but still my page did not work, while showcase page worked. To avoid possible configuration differences, I even used (tweaked) web.xml and faces-config.xml from showcase. 
Server is Jboss 7.1.1.
Comparison (view source from browser) of showcase page and my page shows that my page is missing

> RichFaces.queue.setQueueOptions

in script generated in header.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that PrimeFaces library is the culprit. The project was migrated from RichFaces 3 and the only reason I used PrimeFaces was spacer tag. After removing PrimeFaces library from web project, and implementing spacer with the help of JBoss [forum](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SpacerImplementationForJSF2OrRichFaces4), problem was solved.